# Firebase Functions HTTPS 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I built a Firebase HTTP Event function with Node and Express. The function is working, but when I invoke the function on the client side I get `403 Forbidden`. The first time I invoked the function I was asked to sign in with a Google account. I signed in with the same account I use for Firebase, but when I invoked the function I got:

[Screenshot of 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22q6.png)

I looked at the use roles on Google cloud platform and the permission to invoke the function is set to `allUsers`. I signed out and back in again in the Firebase CLI.

Here is the `index.js` in the functions folder:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.port || 5600
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.use(express.static('Public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});

app.post("/api/user", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('../Public/bedankt.html', {root: __dirname})
  const persGegevens = req.body

  const string = JSON.stringify(persGegevens, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string"){
      return value.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return value
    }
  }, 1);

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'gietvloermakers@gmail.com',
      pass: 'Gietvloermakers2020!'
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'gietvloermakers@gmail.com',
    to: 'gvbeusekom84@hotmail.com',
    subject: 'Nieuwe bestelling op Gietvloermakers',
    html: string
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
});

exports.app1 = functions.https.onRequest(app);

app.listen(port);

console.log(port);
```

Here is the html:

```html
<form id="controlleer-form" action="/api/user" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="controleer-div">
        <h2>Uw bestelling</h2>
        <p>Aantal m2</p>
        <input class="controle-input" type="text" name="aantalM2" id="aantalM2" readonly>
        <p>Kleur</p>
        <input class="controle-input" type="text" name="kleur" id="kleur" readonly>
        <p>Assistentie</p>
        <input class="controle-input" type="text" name="assistentie" id="assistentie" readonly>
        <p>Gereedschappen</p>
        <input class="controle-input" type="text" name="gereedschappen" id="gereedschappen" readonly>
        <p>Totale prijs</p>
        <input  class="controle-input" type="text" name="totale-prijs" id="totale-prijs" readonly>
        <a href="bestellen.html"><p id="andere-kleur">Bestelling aanpassen</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="controleer-div">
        <h2>Uw gegevens</h2>
        <p>Voornaam</p>
        <input type="text" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
        <p>Achternaam</p>
        <input type="text" name="Achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam">
        <p>Straatnaam en huisnummer</p>
        <input type="text" name="Achternaam" placeholder="Straatnaam en huisnummer">
        <p>Postcode</p>
        <input type="text" name="Achternaam" placeholder="Postcode">
        <p>Telefoonnummer</p>
        <input type="tel" name="telefoonnummer" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
        <p>Emailadres</p>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Emailadres"><br>
        <input id="verzenden" type="submit"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "Public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app1"
    }]
  }
}
```

I tried but I exhausted all possible solutions I've found online so far.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I encountered this recently. It turns out that as of January 15, 2020 new functions require authentication by default.

See [the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation) for details.

The solution was to manually add the `Cloud Functions Invoker` permission to the `allUsers` user in the Cloud Functions page in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: In my case, the Cloud Functions Invoker was added as a default (without my doing), but it still did not work.

Comment: Same for me the rule is by default added, still can't access the function. Google firebase needs to work on their documentations

Comment: Thanks lot, this documentation should be linked/referenced in the Firebase functions documentation.

Answer (score 21):

If you are getting 403 forbidden error like below

> Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL
> /api/test from this server.

Please follow below steps to grant access to all users. Basically this is to allow unauthenticated clients to access your api endpoint.

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list
- Select the function to which you want to give public access
- Click on PERMISSIONS
- Click on ADD MEMBER
- Type allUsers
- Select role Cloud Functions -> Cloud Functions Invoker
- Save

That's it, now test your api.

Comment: In my case (Next.JS 13 using app router) I needed to add "Cloud Run Invoker" to "allUsers" as well

Answer (score 8):

This has to do with permission access to your cloud functions http requests and cloud function events, you need to edit your cloud function IAM permission.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

Comment: Thanks for you answer @BadMask121! I solved the problem a couple of weeks ago by changing the IAM permissions indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem (was asked to login with my Google Account, then denied access). It turned out that functions do currently not work outside the default region. In my case, I had to make a change here:

```
 exports.app = functions
  .region('europe-west6') // does not work, delete this line
  .https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code exports the express application as the Cloud Function `app1` on this line:

```js
exports.app1 = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In your screenshot, you have tried to access the non-existent `app` Cloud Function instead resulting in the `403 Forbidden` response.

This means the correct URL to call from your client is

```
http://us-central1-gietvloermakers.cloudfunctions.net/app1/api/user
                                                      ^^^^
```

(or you could change the name of the export to `app`)

Having a closer look at your source code, you should also remove the following lines. If you wanted to test your code you would instead use `firebase serve`.

```
const port = process.env.port || 5600
/* ... */
app.listen(port);
```

On the following lines, you also inject the body parser twice.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // use this

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}); // or this, not both

app.post("/api/user", urlencodedParser, ...
```

In your code, you also have:

```
app.post("/api/user", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('../Public/bedankt.html', {root: __dirname})
  /* do some other stuff */
})
```

This is invalid for a Cloud Function, because as soon as the Cloud Function handler (your code) calls `end()`, `redirect()` or `send()`, the Cloud Function is allowed to be terminated at any time which means that your email may never be sent. To fix this you need to send the file last.

```
app.post("/api/user", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  /* do some other stuff */
  res.sendFile('../Public/bedankt.html', {root: __dirname})
});
```

My last observation, is that the error may be caused by the folder `Public` not existing on the server. Based on your `sendFile` call, you are expecting that the folder "Public" is available to your deployed function but as it is not inside the `functions` folder, it will not be deployed with your code.

```
res.sendFile('../Public/bedankt.html', {root: __dirname})
```

As this file would also be accessible at `your-domain.com/bedankt.html`, we'll redirect to it. If you wanted to send the HTML content of this file instead, move it inside your deployed functions directory.

```
res.redirect('/bedankt.html')
```

Because you appear to be trying to use your express function behind Firebase hosting, we can trim your `index.js` file to the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const apiApp = express();

apiApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

apiApp.post("/api/user", (req, res) => {
  const persGegevens = req.body

  const string = JSON.stringify(persGegevens, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string"){
      return value.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      return value
    }
  }, 1);

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'gietvloermakers@gmail.com',
      pass: 'Gietvloermakers2020!'
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'gietvloermakers@gmail.com',
    to: 'gvbeusekom84@hotmail.com',
    subject: 'Nieuwe bestelling op Gietvloermakers',
    html: string
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.redirect('/bedankt.html?success=0');
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.redirect('/bedankt.html?success=1');
    }
  });  
});

// note rename to api
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(apiApp);
```

which requires updating your `firebase.json` file to:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "Public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/api/**",
      "function": "api"
    }]
  }
}
```

This configuration will first attempt to find a matching file in your `Public` directory. If it can't find a match, it will check if the requested path starts with `/api` and if so, launch your Cloud Function. If it still can't find a match, it will show your 404 page (or the built in one if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I first wrote the function I exported the function as exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app); When I invoked the function back then it gave me the same error. I changed the function name to app1 to see what happened, but nothing changed. I was asked to sign in to a google account again and got the same 403 error after signing in. When I invoke the function again it just says Forbidden.

Comment: @GijsvanBeusekom Please see added documentation.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman for all your pointers. I implemented the code-changes and I now get a cannot post error. It says the path is /gietvloermakers/us-central1/api/api/app1. Because I wanted to get the website live today is changed the res.sendfile to res.send with some simple html to get an acceptable product. I'm still curious to what went wrong. Did the "rewrite{source} in firebase.json create the double api in the path?

Comment: @GijsvanBeusekom Based on the GitHub repo I can see, you still need to remove `app.use(express.static('Public'));` (Firebase hosting will be in charge of serving files from Public) and you should be able to use `res.sendFile('./bedankt.html', {root: __dirname})` as `bedankt.html` is in your functions folder.

Comment: I also made a mistake in my `index.js` above, the route should be `/api/user`, because when called from hosting, express will be passed `https://gietvloermakers.nl/api/user` instead of what I was expecting. This does mean that calling it directly would be done at `http://us-central1-gietvloermakers.cloudfunctions.net/[EXPORT_NAME]/api/user` (which if exported as `api` would mean it would be at `http://us-central1-gietvloermakers.cloudfunctions.net/api/api/user`

Comment: thanks for your in dept problem solving. I still don't really understand the way Firebase uses the http://us-central1-gietvloermakers.cloudfunctions.net/[EXPORT_NAME]/api/user endpoint. I will be using using Firebase functions again for coming projects, so thank you a lot for all your insights!

Comment: @GijsvanBeusekom Message me on the [Firebase Slack](https://firebase.community) and I'll see if I can clear up that confusion

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me:

1. Delete `gcf-artifacts` in [https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/browse/{projectName}](https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/browse/%7BprojectName%7D)
2. Delete functions in [https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{projectName}/functions](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/%7BprojectName%7D/functions)
3. Deploy Firebase functions