# Firebase function not serving routes when deployed

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Some context to my problem:
I'm wanting to write a firebase function including Express that sits in between a users' browser and the Notion API. I drafted up [some code for minimal functionality](https://github.com/pascalstockert/notion-blog/blob/feature/api/functions/src/index.ts) which works with the local emulators firebase provides. I've tested the two routes locally, both are served properly and execute without error.

When I try to deploy the function all goes well. However, upon calling [the route](https://us-central1-pasu-notion-blog.cloudfunctions.net/api/api/posts) it responds with a 403 error page. No other errors logged, just this "Error: Forbidden" disclaimer.

Am I missing something really obvious here or using functions outside of their intended scope?

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot your deployment following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#serving)?
Also, I noticed that _the route_ you've posted on your question seems to be working as intended; could you please confirm if you're still having the issue?

Comment: I fixed the issue - it was indeed a problem with the underlying rules for cloud functions and who may invoke them. I needed to give the *allUsers* user the permission to invoke the function.

Comment: Would you mind to post your solution as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it!

The 403 Error did originate from the cloud function itself. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60939224/8031259) explains it quite well - it's an issue of missing permissions when trying to call a function which is resolved by adding the `Cloud Functions Invoker` permission to the `allUsers` user of your cloud function.