# Firestore Cloud Function API Endpoint

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want anyone (unauthenticated users) to be able to call an API an return the tier of plan they are on depending on their FN, LN, DOB. I created an HTTP endpoint via a Cloud Function but receive a 403 error even after updating permissions.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const checkEligibility = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const dateOfBirth = new Date(req.body.dateOfBirth);

  console.log(firstName);

  const eligibleUsersRef = admin.firestore().collection("eligible_people");
  const querySnapshot = await eligibleUsersRef
    .where("firstName", "==", firstName)
    .where("lastName", "==", lastName)
    .where("dob", "==", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(dateOfBirth))
    .get();

  if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    // User is not eligible, return an error message
    res.status(403).send("User is not eligible");
  } else {
    // User is eligible, return the name of the tier
    const eligibleUser = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
    res.json({tier: eligibleUser.tier});
  }
});
```

When I call this function from an app, I receive the following log:

```
Function execution took 4077 ms, finished with status code: 403
```

I've updated the permissions of this in the Google Cloud so that all users are invokers, similar to this: [Firebase Functions HTTPS 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237167/firebase-functions-https-403-forbidden). However, I'm still getting this 403 error--what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try running it without the following where clause `.where("dob", "==", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(dateOfBirth))`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thank you!! That worked...do you know what was causing the issue with the date?

Comment: Are you sure the Timestamp based on the DOB is exactly the same in the DB and in the Cloud Function? You may store the DOB as a simple string like formatted as YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Thanks! this was the issue! appreciate your help and happy to approve the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `Timestamp.fromDate()` method is different from the time Timestamp stored in the database. The consequence is that your `querySnapshot` is always empty.

Since you select on a date (and not a date/time) I advise to use a simple string formatted for example as `YYYYMMDD`.